# Python list messing up

Tags: python, list, loops

So I have some code:

```
nlist = [0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,2,0]
count = 0
for i in nlist:
    if nlist[i] == 0:
        nlist.remove(nlist[i])
        count += 1
        if count == 4:
            count = 0
print(nlist)
```

And when ever i run it the Output is:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0]
```

Even though the output should be this:

```
[2]
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Is `i` an element or index?  You're using it in both ways.

Comment: i is an index...

Comment: @J.Doe no, it's not: `for i in nlist:` will give you the elements of `nlist`, I didn't even notice that error. But that and iterating while you mutate are the source of your problems

Comment: count backwards, `for i in xrange(len(nlist)-1, -1, -1):`

Comment: @Alex although you *can* do it that way, it is inefficient and error prone. It's almost always better just to create a new list.